# Is there any prefeered Python package to create lis type of file(output file generated by SQR)

Tags: python, lis, sqr

I have to create **.lis**(output generated from SQR) type of file using python.
I am not able to find any existing python package for it.
please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The LIS files are just text files.

We created our own python library that allows us to use print positioning like SQR does, including support for page count, headers, footers, landscape, and portrait. They are not offering it to the public at this time.

It shouldn't be too hard to create a your own python package to do this yourself.